# I want to just log all the columns of the table with new or old values, but the trigger fails to compile

Tags: triggers, firebird

I want to create a trigger on firebird db:

```
SET TERM ^ ;
create trigger log_trigger_error for test
  before insert or update
as
begin
  INSERT INTO test_log (a,b)
    select case when (new.rdb$field_name is null and old.rdb$field_name  is not null 
                    or new.rdb$field_name is not null and old.rdb$field_name is null 
                    or new.rdb$field_name <> old.rdb$field_name) 
                then  new.rdb$field_name   
                else old.rdb$field_name as a
        end , 2 as b 
    from rdb$relation_fields
    where rdb$relation_name ='TEST';

end^

SET TERM ; ^
```

Comment: Could you describe what this trigger is supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a trigger for the table `test` but then in the trigger body you use `new` and `old` context variables on a select from table `rdb$relation_fields`. That's not possible, the `new` and `old` variables are only available for the table the trigger is for.

If you want to log changes to the data then use trigger like

```
create trigger log_trigger_error for test before update
as
begin
  INSERT INTO test_log (a, b) VALUES(old.a, old.b);
end^
```

Now when record in the `test` table is updated the old values are logged into `test_log` table.

Comment: It feels like the code in the question was copied and modified from code that logged field renames. Maybe `values (case when old.a is distinct from new.a then old.a else null end, case when old.b is distinct from new.b then old.b else null end)` and an if to only insert when either or both are distinct might achieve what the OP seems to want to do.